# String Join with Mutiple String

Tags: c#

I am trying to concat my string with List.

For Example:

```
ID Number, List string 1, List string 2...
```

because I need the "," between the string.
So I use string join but it won't work.
Here is my code below.

My code:

```
String IDnumber = string.Join(", ", owner.ID , customerID.Select(x => x.ID).ToList());
```

I am wondering if there is any workaround.

Comment: `string.Join(", ", customerID.Select(x => x.ID).Prepend(owner.ID))` or `$"{owner.ID}, {string.Join(", ", customerID.Select(x => x.ID))}"`

Comment: Can you be more specific about your expected output and actual output?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate things: `IDnumber = $"{owner.ID}, {string.Join(", ", customerID.Select(x => x.ID).ToList())}";`

Comment: Thanks so much @canton7
string.Join(", ", customerID.Select(x => x.ID).Prepend(owner.ID)) work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you appear to be using

```
public static string Join (char separator, params object?[] values)
```

Therefore, you are essentially calling

```
string.Join(", ", [first part], [second part])
```

If your `owner.ID` is 123, with your list of customers, I presume your output looks something like this

```
123, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

This happens because you are not joining your `owner.ID` and each element in the list of customers, but rather the `owner.ID` and the entire list of customers as one object.

The correct approach would be something like

```
string.Join(", ", customerID.Select(x => x.ID).Prepend(owner.ID))
```

or

```
$"{owner.ID}, {string.Join(", ", customerID.Select(x => x.ID))}"
```

or

```
new StringBuilder().Append(owner.ID).Append(", ").Append(string.Join(", ", customerID.Select(x => x.ID))).ToString()
```

Comment: or my personal favorite: `string.Join(", ", new[] { owner.ID }.Concat(customerID.Select(x => x.ID)))`.

Comment: @Heinzi Why would that be a favourite? It allocates an entirely unnecessary array

Comment: @Heinzi There are many ways, and that works as well. However, with your example, you are allocating a new list to your memory, which is not needed to produce the desired result.

Comment: @canton7: I consider it easier to read, because the items appear in the same order in my source code in which they appear in the final list.

Comment: @ThomasAngeland: True, but allocating a single element array is a very light-weight operation. And it's (currently) the canonical/idiomatic way to create a singleton IEnumerable in C#.

Comment: @Heinzi If the code doesn't need to be super performant or efficient, I can't disagree.

Comment: @ThomasAngeland: Well, if the code needs to be super performant or efficient, *all* suggested solutions need to be re-evaluated. After all, `Prepend` internally creates an `AppendPrependIterator` on the heap, etc. Just because the array creation is visible in code does not automatically mean that it's more expensive than all the stuff hidden behind .NET library method calls. ;-)